# Overwrite /system/bin/su using adb

Tags: rooting, tablet, superuser, arm-processors

Can't overwrite su file in /system/bin/ my stupid classmate put a prank on me and inserted a different su binary coming from his linux pc instead of the already existing su in /system/xbin/

I want to overwrite it myself since even him can't do it

here's the adb shell su return:

> /system/bin/su: not executable: magic 7F45

Is there a way to replace this one with the already existing su in /system/xbin/? I've been trying to chmod the su overwritten su file for 3 months now.. I can't even chown cause IDK what are the users and IDK how to list all of them. Help. Thanks in advance.

P.S.

### -can't load custom rom since I'm still on the way of rooting phone

### -can't load stock rom for I'm using a very rare tablet (Arc Mobile 727M) can't find a good alternative for stock rom

Comment: What is the device? Maybe you can get around it if you can flash a stock ROM

Comment: Arc Mobile 727M (one with the TV, and Dual Sim)

Comment: Has it a custom recovery installed? If so, have you tried from there?

Comment: like I said I can't since I'm still on my way of rooting it... I asked my classmate to install the custom recovery but instead put a prank on me -_-

also a custom recovery won't actually replace the overwritten su without a custom rom or stock rom

Comment: Can't you specifically run adb ./system/xbin/su?That should work.

Comment: yeah I can but some apps can't detect it as a working su since it refers to the overwritten su which can't be run in arm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrew, if su binary in xbin is proper, then run,

```
adb shell
/system/xbin/su -c mv /system/bin/su /system/bin/su-dead
```

then reboot and open terminal emulator and run su.

Did this device come pre-rooted? If not then what prevents you
from repeating the process you used to root?

Comment: no it's not pre-rooted, thanks btw rooted my phone already...